# Is it possible to make bottom border auto-resizeable (according to text width in last row) in html5 page?

Tags: css, html, layout

Is it possible to make bottom border auto-resizeable (according to text width in last row) in html5 page? (e.g. if there is third row - there should be a hole in border).

Background image can be different. Is it possible to implement this?

[image]

Comment: To be able to replicate that background-image slice arbitrarily, I doubt it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

maybe not a perfect solution by it's not a bad idea...continue from here ;)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="column side">
</div>
<div class="column content">    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</div>
<div class="column side">
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.wrap
{
    border-top: 3px solid;
    border-left: 3px solid;
    border-right: 3px solid;
    position: relative;
}

.column
{
    float: left;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
}

.column.content
{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 2%;
}

.column.side
{
    width: 5%;
}

.no_border
{
    border: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contentOuterHeight_start = $('.column.content').outerHeight();
    var contentHeight_start = $('.column.content').height();
    $('.column.side').css('height', contentOuterHeight_start);
    var lineHeight = $('.content').css('line-height').replace('px', '');
    threeRows = lineHeight * 3;
    if (contentHeight_start == threeRows){
        $('.column.content').addClass('no_border');   
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        threeRows = lineHeight * 3;
        var contentOuterHeight_resize = $('.column.content').outerHeight();
        var contentHeight_resize = $('.column.content').height();
        $('.column.side').css('height', contentOuterHeight_resize);
        if (contentHeight_resize == threeRows){        
            $('.column.content').addClass('no_border');   
        }
        else {
            $('.column.content').removeClass('no_border');       
        }
    });


});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g454305r/